# How can one delete all text message threads except for a few ones on Pixel 6?

Tags: delete, google-pixel-6, google-messages, cleanup

I have plenty of text messages for OTP or similar automated services on my Google Pixel 6. I'm doing some cleaning. How can one delete all text message threads except for a few ones on Pixel 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware in newer versions of Messages, you can go to

```
Profile Pic - Message Settings - Message Organization
```

and enable the option "Auto-delete OTPs after 24 hours"... this can help a lot.

[image: Message Organization Settings]

Otherwise Messages doesn't have the kind of granularity to mass delete multiple entire threads, you would have to switch to Textra or something like that to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There exists no built-in solution to delete all text message threads except for a few ones on Pixel 6. Android does not offer any built-in solution for that use case.